# What other tools and frameworks i should aware of before start learning windows7 mobile programming?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I am going to learn Windows7 mobile programming soon, what are tools and frameworks I should make sure to know very well before start.

For example, is know silverlight or wpf is something important? what else important?

Comment: FYI, the last version of "Windows Mobile" is 6.5 (I think).  Microsoft's next generation of phone products after Windows Mobile is called "Windows Phone" and the numbering starts with "Windows Phone 7".  If you're looking for resources to develop on the latest platform, I'd suggest searching for "Windows Phone 7" instead of "Windows 7 mobile".  Try http://developer.windowsphone.com

Comment: Yes, thanks for advice and URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WP7 is all based on Silverlight. Know it well.

If you're developing games, you'll need to know [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/gettingstarted) as well.

You will also most definitely want to familiarize yourself with [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) development and the [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework. They will make your apps much cleaner and easier to work with.

...of course, with all that said you're going to need a strong foundation in .NET development (Most examples you are going to find are C# based so I'd recommend either getting cozy with C# or with how to convert C# to VB.NET EXTREMELY well).

Comment: And what about WPF? is it important as well? as i see in your  Model-View-ViewModel link it point to a wpf article.

Comment: @Amr: it may or may not be important.  It depends on what you plan on doing.

Comment: Silverlight can be seen as a super-set of WPF. Silverlight just has less access to certain Framework features. Learning WPF certainly wouldn't hurt, but it's not going to be that beneficial to WP7 development.

Comment: FYI, Silverlight is a smaller subset of WPF. For the purposes of WP7 development you can ignore WPF.

Answer (score 3):

For Phone7 the (only?) choices are SilverLight and XNA.

A very good understanding of .NET is important for both.