# Silverlight on WP7

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm going to get a WP7 silverlight project at work, and I'd like to ask you guys what documentation do you recommend to somebody who's willing to write silverlight apps for WP7 but who's never touched silverlight itself before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I maintain a list of Windows Phone 7 developer resources in [this page](http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/windows-phone-7-resources/). You can start by watching the "[Windows Phone 7 in 7 minutes](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/SeriesDescription.aspx?CourseId=158)" videos and continue with the Windows Phone 7 training kit.

Answer (score 1):

Get on Silverlight.net and watch some videos.  Silverlight and WPF is very different from most other UI frameworks, so you really just want to get the hang of the approach, the different containers, etc.

Check out the links under Start Learning Silverlight here:

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/

Also, Tim Heuer's blog is filled with great Silverlight tutorials and info:

http://timheuer.com/blog/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the links others have added about resources for learing Silverlight.

If you're new to mobile development it's also VERY important to understand how developing for mobile/phones is different from developing for the web or PC.

Please also check out the answers to the following, very similar, questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491419/good-tutorials-for-learning-c-for-windows-phone-7-development

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716043/windows-phone-7-good-early-learning-source

[What other tools and frameworks i should aware of before start learning windows7 mobile programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761666/what-other-tools-and-frameworks-i-should-aware-of-before-start-learning-windows7)

[What are the main pain points, when learning Windows Phone 7 programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852944/what-are-the-main-pain-points-when-learning-windows-phone-7-programming)

Comment: I've already developed on Android so I kinda have an idea on the difference between PC dev. and Phone dev. even though I'm gonna check your links. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The best for beginners: Windows Phone Programming Blue Book. It can be downloaded [here](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/).

Have fun with WP7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Windows Phone 7 developer training kit](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/WP7TrainingKit/)? At the very least it is a good collection of sample projects that would be worth looking at if you're just starting out :)